# SyntaxError when running a React project the path to which contains an apostrophe

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, npx

Whenever I try to run my React App, it sometimes throws me the following error.

```text
Error:- 
file:///C:/Users/Vighnesh's%20PC/Projects/MERN%20Projects/Blog%20App/client/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:2
/* build-hook-start *//*00001*/try { require('c:\\users\\vighnesh's pc\\.vscode\\extensions\\wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.237\\out\\buildhook\\index.js').default({tool: 'vite'}); } catch(cjsError) { try { import('file:///c:/users/vighnesh's%20pc/.vscode/extensions/wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.237/out/buildhook/index.js').then(m => m.default.default({tool: 'vite'})).catch(esmError => {}) } catch(esmError) {}}/* build-hook-end */
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:68:21)
```

One fix which I found was, deleting node modules and package-lock.json file and reinstalling it. This solves the issue temporarily. But isn't there any permanent solution for this? I tried installing react-app using "npx create-react-app" and tried with "npm create vite" as well but still the error persists. Please Guide me out of this.

Comment: Pretty horrifying that whatever’s responsible for this isn’t escaping inserted text in dynamically generated code. Do you have the “Console Ninja” VS Code extension installed? Try uninstalling that, if so. File a bug report with them if that fixes it.